# iOS localization. Aim to localize strings in all languages, but images in only some languages

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, localization

I'd like to localize my application with the following pattern:

- Localize all strings (say English, French and German ([don't mention the war!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xnNhzgcWTk)))
- Localize some images in some languages (say just English and French)

I can localize the strings without issue. My problem is that when I add the German strings, the other resources that are localized into English and French attempt to find a German version. I don't want to provide a German version (trying to avoid too many superfluous images as they bulk up the size of the app).

Can anyone suggest a way of telling the application not to bother looking for a German version of the images.

My problem isn't adding languages, it's ignoring them under certain conditions. I don't want to include a German version of "a.png", but I do want to include a French version of "a.png". When the user's language is set to German, I'd like it to select the default language which is English.

Comment: explained more: My problem isn't adding languages, it's ignoring them under certain conditions. I don't want to include a German version of "a.png", but I do want to include a French version of the same file. When the user's language is set to German, I'd like it to select the default language which is English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having had the same issue I want to follow up on this as the suggested resolution did not work exactly as quoted.

My setup is 3 localized languages, de, en, fr. The .lproj folders Xcode created are thus named

```
en.lproj
de.lproj
fr.lproj
```

I have a graphical button with "start" on it that needs localization from english to french but not to german (as it is the same word).

My "Localization native development region" was set to "English", which must have been the default (maybe a while back, the project has been a wip for quite a while).

The button did not show up on german devices. Switching to "EN" or any of the suggestions from Xcode ("United Kingdom", "United States of America") did not resolve the issue.

The solution was simpel. The string in the "Localization native development region" needs to exactly match the (native language).lproj string. So setting it to "en" it finally resolved the issue.

Hope this helps whoever stumbles upon this question.

Answer (score 0):

iOS (and Mac OS) should always fall back to the app's default language. If you don't include the image.png in the de.lproj resources folder, the app should use the en.lproj/image.png file in its place.

Look for key: "Localization native development region" in the Target > Info pane of Xcode. Make sure that says EN.

Comment: I thought this would be the case, but my application doesn't do that. My 'Localization native development region' is indeed already set to EN

Comment: That should be `English.lproj/` not `en.lproj`

Comment: Though I couldn't get this to work in the project about which the question was asked, I tried it with a new project and it did work. Hopefully this answer will help somebody in the future.

Comment: English.lproj is the *old* naming structure pre-Leopard. Apple recommend using en.lproj now. Indeed all new projects created in Xcode 3.2 or later will by default be en.lproj

Answer (score -1):

I don't have that much experience but as far as I'm concerned, your program should just look for the german image, find nothing and then try to load the english image instead.

Comment: With localization in ios, you don't do any  `if (language == 'german')` type code. You just say in your resources 'I have localized for German' and provide German assets.